# Cronjob Raspberry Pi not working

Tags: raspbian, linux, python-3, raspberry-pi-os, cron

I am trying to use my raspi to host a discord bot that every morning publishes the food in my school. I have setup a bronjob with `crontab -e` but it's not working.

Crontab lookis like this:

```
45 07 * 2-5 python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Python/dcfoodbot/new/send.py

30 10 * 1 python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Python/dcfoodbot/new/send.py
```

with blank line at the end. (Published later on mondays because food is updated that day and can sometimes be late). When i tried making it post every minuite for debuging it worked but  setting it to a specific time, for example `26 18 * 2-5 python3....`  did not work. I would really appreciate help!

Thanks!

EDIT:

Changed:

```
45 07 * 2-5 python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Python/dcfoodbot/new/send.py

30 10 * 1 python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Python/dcfoodbot/new/send.py
```

to

45 07 * * 2-5 python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Python/dcfoodbot/new/send.py

30 10 * * 1 python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Python/dcfoodbot/new/send.py

Comment: Your crontab rule only has 4 time specifications.  I think you want something like this 45 07 *  * 1-5. this equates to At 07:45 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday. See this site for details https://crontab.guru/#45_07_*_*_1-5

Comment: You may also try `/full/path/to/python3`.

Comment: @SteveRobillard didn't work :( Tried it and still same result.

Comment: Try replacing cron with systemd-cron. It works the same way but integrates crontab entries into `sudo systemctl`

Comment: You have 2 answers now; have you any feedback or questions?

Answer (score 1):

Your schedules: `45 07 * 2-5` & `30 10 * 1` are incomplete/erroneous. You could use some help from my friend ["The crontab guru"](https://crontab.guru/); it gives you an English-language definition of a schedule that you input, and allows you to verify your *schedule expression*. Note that there are 5 fields, but you seem to have supplied only 4.

AFAIK, `cron` does verify *schedule expressions* for validity, and consequently it *"fails silently"* rather than throwing an error. Perhaps this verification is a [difficult thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57639657/5395338) to do?

Nevertheless, it's always good practice to throw errors. Since `cron` is not attached to a user terminal, you typically won't see errors thrown by your `cron` jobs at the console. However, you may use a *redirect* in your `crontab` entry to capture those error (`stderr`) messages generated by your script. For example:

```
# FROM: 
python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Python/dcfoodbot/new/send.py

TO:
python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Python/dcfoodbot/new/send.py 2>> /home/pi/Desktop/myfailures.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the path of your Python environment first, and after that add the path to your Python script. This is (like) one of my settings:

```
30 23 * * * /home/pi/myprojectfolder/venv/bin/python /home/pi/myprojectfolder/scraper.py
```

Since my project runs in a virtual environment (the folder called `venv`, where I have lots of different packages installed), I let the system know I want to use that Python interpreter. After that, I tell the system what script to run.

If you don't have a virtual environment, try using your system's default Python path. Find out what that is by typing `which python` in your shell. You will get something like `usr/bin/python` and that will be your path.

So, in crontab you will have a single line with 3 commands, all separated by white space:

1. when to run? (run every day at 23.30)
2. where is Python?
3. where is the script I want to run?

To see how to properly generate cron commands, see the website crontab.guru.

I hope it helps.